# Simple password validation c# MVC

Tags: c#, validation, security, asp.net-mvc-4, passwords

I'm making a simple news feed where i enter a new item from a form hidden on a url that i manually need to type in (no account functionality). But i wanted a additional line of defense if the form is found so i added a password field so if the password match the preset i have then the form saves the data in to a xml file.

Now the question is, whats the best practice here to make that validation and where do i put the password?

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult AddPost(AddPostModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && model.Password == "MyPassword")
    {
        AddPostModel.AddPostToXML(model);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The thing is that its a small site and at worst they add news item that should not be there. So do i need to take additional precautions or is it secure enough for what its supposed to protect?

Since i'm quite new i don't have a lot of experience in security so any guidelines or what to keep in mind would also be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion i settled on having a hashed password in the web.config that i then check against to see if the password is the right one. Then during the check i just hash the entered password with the same function and check if its a match.

Here is the class i built if any one else is looking for something similar. =)

```
public class Security
{
    public static bool ValidatePassword(string password)
    {
        string hashValue = HashPassword(password);

        if (hashValue == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"])
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    private static string HashPassword(string passwordToHash)
    {
        HashAlgorithm hash = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordToHash);
        byte[] hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextBytes);

        //in this string you got the encrypted password
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found useful link that might help you to have an idea about customising the security level http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jitendra1987/password-validator-in-C-Sharp/
Have you looked at the Ajax toolkits!? They have good mechanisms to setup your first line of security defence i.e. length of password, adding complexity and other features. Please have a look at: http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/PasswordStrength/PasswordStrength.aspx

Comment: The issue was not that i needed validation of a new password but validation if the entered password was the same as a predefined one that i set for when i enter news items to the site.